# Why doesn't the date function throw me an error?

Tags: php, date

I'm just curious as to how I can make the date function throw an error for invalid dates. Here is what I tried, and the outputs are in comments. see below:

```
echo date("n",strtotime("Nov"))."\n"; //outputs 11 as expected
echo date("n",strtotime("nov"))."\n"; //outputs 11 as expected
echo date("n",strtotime("dec"))."\n"; //outputs 12 as expected 
echo date("n",strtotime("nova"))."\n"; //outputs 12 but instead I expected an error
```

Is there a simple function I can use to make sure the textual date is valid or do I have to roll off my own array to test for it?

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php  `Returns a formatted date string. If a non-numeric value is used for timestamp, FALSE is returned and an E_WARNING level error is emitted.`. Ditto for strtotime. It returns boolean false on failure, which date() will see as integer `0`.  If you had `date('r',...)` you'd see you have Dec 1969, since almost certainly you're in GMT+x timezone.

Comment: "//outputs 12 but instead I expected an error" - it should print `1` for january (1st, 1970); the same as for `date("n", false)` and `date("n", 0)`

Comment: @VolkerK It does, see https://eval.in/472105

Answer (score 0):

The function returns true/false according to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
if (($timestamp = strtotime($str)) === false) {
    // could not be parsed
} else {
    // valid
}
```